# Why does $.getJSON not execute code in callback?

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have the following JQuery:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(init);
        function init() {
            console.log('before');
            $.getJSON('data.txt', function(data) {
                console.log('inside');
                alert(data);
            });
            console.log('after');

        }
    </script>
```

And `data.txt` looks like this:

```
{
    'one','111',
    'two','222',
    'three','333'
}
```

But in the console window, I just get:

```
before    
after
```

Why is the code in the callback not executing?

### addendum

@newman, in my network tab in Chrome, here is the data.txt file:

[image]

### addendum 2

in Firefox, it says that it is reading it between "before" and "after" but never prints  "inside" to the console or executes the alert

[image]

Comment: May be script finding data.txt in other folder that you expect. Check on "Network" or "Console" tab in FireBug what request is run for correct url.

Comment: @newman see above, it seems to be loading the file, or at least can recognize that it is in the same directory as index.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is failing silently. The content of data.txt is not well-formed JSON. It should be:

```
{
    "one":"111",
    "two":"222",
    "three":"333"
}
```

If data.txt is found and its content returned and successfully parsed, you should get in console:

```
before
after
inside
```

Comment: In firefox, it says that it is reading in the file, see above, which is odd. Does the JSON need to be formatted differently. I changed the file form to UTF-8 as well, no change.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay - have you changed the content of the file according to my suggestion?